Why do I have to change the password from sudo user to access root?
Debian 12, after connecting with SSH, to access root I am always required to:
user@debian:~$ sudo passwd root
This resets the password of root, and then it is able to login to root with root@ip in a new terminal?
/etc/ssh/sshd_config shows root permit to yes.

Don't log in as root. Use sudo or similar frameworks.

You are attempting to do very wrong thing. We won't help you to do that here (think: we won't help you to aim the gun into your foot to shoot). Rather, I'd better describe the way you should be managing Linux system.
Don't work as root. In particular, never allow obtaining a root shell directly from the network, especially with password, e.g. via SSH.
Locally, use sudo, doas or similar frameworks. But resist the temptation even to create users that can sudo any command, that's too overpowered, especially for automated tasks. Each such user is a breach in a security. Define the roles for your users and only allow their sudo to run minimally needed set for that role.
Remote automation tools can use it too; for instance, learn how to become with Ansible.
If you create local automated tasks that use sudo, they are likely to run very specific commands that are well known beforehand; for such tasks, you create dedicated files in /etc/sudoers.d/ which permit exactly that command to be run. It may grow info a few dozens of such individually permitted commands; that's normal, this is how it should be. Don't try to "optimize" that or "ease" the management by permitting everything to a some "super sudoer"; that's no better that working as root and should be avoided for the same reason.
There is a valid use of root over SSH, like backups and other automated actions. You setup limited root SSH access for that using SSH keys. But first you need to reset sshd_config to the default value of PermitRootLogin prohibit-password. It's made default for a good reason.
Then you put keys into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, but restrict their capabilities (and thus limit the damage one can incur if the corresponding private key is leaked). The correct way is to use restrict and then specify allowed action for that key (e.g. forced command, enabled forwarding, etc.). See man authorized_keys for the details, and ask another question, dedicated to setting up some particular key for some concrete problem.
This is the valid best practice of setting up SSH and privilege escalation.
